# android App is launching automatically after minimizing app

Tags: java, android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG,"OnCreate()");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    mTextview = findViewById(R.id.title);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment, new OneFragment());
            //ft.commit();
            ft.addToBackStack("frag");

            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

after minimizing my android app again its opening automatically.please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Most likely, it is not the `onCreate()` that causes an app to re-open... What code do you have in `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`?

Comment: i got the answer,i used finish() method inside OnPause() method.

Comment: Very good you found the reason yourself!

Answer (score 1):

The Correct way to manage the handler is,
In your activity add this code,

```
        private void initTasks() {
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initTasks();
    }
```

Then to stop opening your app after minimizing,

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        handler.removeCallbacks(null);
    }
```